# How can i use the Object tracking API of vision framework on ios11?

Tags: objective-c, ios11, coreml, apple-vision

```
// init bounding
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0.3, 0.3);
VNSequenceRequestHandler* reqImages = [[VNSequenceRequestHandler alloc] init];
VNRectangleObservation* ObserveRect = [VNRectangleObservation observationWithBoundingBox:rect];
VNTrackRectangleRequest* reqRect = [[VNTrackRectangleRequest alloc] initWithRectangleObservation:ObserveRect];
NSArray<VNRequest *>* requests = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:reqRect, nil];
BOOL bsucc = [reqImages performRequests:requests onCGImage:img.CGImage error:&error];

// get tracking bounding
VNDetectRectanglesRequest* reqRectTrack = [VNDetectRectanglesRequest new];
NSArray<VNRequest *>* requestsTrack = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:reqRectTrack, nil];
[reqImages performRequests:requestsTrack onCGImage:img.CGImage error:&error];

VNRectangleObservation* Observe = [reqRectTrack.results firstObject];
CGRect boundingBox = Observe.boundingBox;
```

Why the boundingBox value is incorrect?

How can i find the demo of vision.framework of ios11 ?

Comment: I run into the same problem as you, I have found the example used in Vision Keynote, they do resizing on `boundingBox` values. But not working on my side. Here is the sample : https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/ImageClassificationwithVisionandCoreML.zip Let me know if you find the solution

Comment: I find the demo in the Keynote too，

'
// Create  request handler
let  requestHandler = VNSequenceRequestHandler()

// Start the tracking with an observation
let observations = detectionRequest.results    as! [VNDetectedObjectObservation]
let objectsToTrack = observations.map { VNTrackObjectRequest(detectedObjectObservation: $0) }

// Run the requests
requestHandler.perform(objectsToTrack, on: pixelBuffer)

// Lets look at the results
for  request    in  objectsToTrack
    for    observation in  request.results as! [VNDetectedObjectObservation]

'
but it don't working.

Comment: @Alberl Do you got any solution for detecting object from static image , I am facing problem for converting the points from one coordinate system to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my simple example of using Vision framework: https://github.com/artemnovichkov/iOS-11-by-Examples. I guess you have a problem with different coordinate systems. Pay attention to rect converting:

`cameraLayer.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: originalRect)`

and

`cameraLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: transformedRect)`

Comment: Thanks Artem, you are great ! :)

Comment: Is it possible to detect object in an image and track it into another set of images?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov Thanks for reply. In other way can we implement to local video as I am not able to find method for converting rectangle of interest to specific coordinate space.

Comment: @TheiCoder do you find any examples of object tracking on local videos ?

Comment: @srjohnhuang No, But I used dlib library for object detection from image. You can try with dlib for video.

Answer (score 4):

Vision Framework tracking an object, a demo for this can be found at this link:

https://github.com/jeffreybergier/Blog-Getting-Started-with-Vision
[image: Image Credit: Jeffrey Bergier]

The Blogger goes into great details here of getting the demo working and has a gif showing a working build.

Hope this is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks Luke, you are great ! :)